# How do I install PyGObject?

Tags: python-2.7, pygtk, pygobject

I am trying to install PyGtk on windows 7 for Python 2.7, but when go to use pip to install PyGtk it says i need PyGObject (Go figure) so I installed the Visual C++ package for Python (I know I have the correct version) and tried using pip to install PyGObject but it keeps comming out with an error message saying that cairo.h is missing, and sure enough I check in the directory and it wasn't there. How on earth am I supposed to install PyGObject?

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

There's a quite long way, and it needs some tweaking here and there, but it works. I used Python 3.6, and don't know whether it will work in 2.7.

First, get build scripts for GTK+3 for Windows from here (https://github.com/guruDanny67/gvsbuild). It's a fork from this repo (https://github.com/wingtk/gvsbuild), but it seems to be more up-to-date with the various versions of packages. I used the 'ed2018' branch, which seems to be the most relevant, but the changes from this branch will probably end in 'master', so check the number of commits ahead and behind.

You will also need a Visual Studio 2017 build tools if you don't have C++ workload installed in Visual Studio 2017. You can also use VS 2015, but I didn't try it. 2017 Build tools are here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#other. You should probably also include 'VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 toolset for desktop'.

You'll need a Python installed. I used version 3.6, don't know about the others.

Also, you'll need MSYS2 (http://www.msys2.org/). It's only used for some needed tools.

The compiling/installation is (mostly) quite straightforward, but it takes some time (SSD probably helps a lot). Just read the instructions on the gvsbuild page. If you build piece by piece, it helps to include `--fast-build` parameter in the command line.

You can get the list of all projects than can be build using

```
python build.py list
```

or simply

```
build list
```

if you have a Python launcher installed.

All the options for build:

```
build build --help
```

There's a build project for a pygobject and pycairo, which installs them in the installed Python `site-packages` directory. However, the better way is to uninstall them (use `pip` or just remove directories if pip complains).

Then, download the sources for the PyCairo and PyGObject from the PyPi site (https://pypi.org/project/pycairo/, https://pypi.org/project/PyGObject/). Add the directory with the bunch of `lib` files to your `LIB` environment variable (should be something like `f:\gtk-build\gtk\Win32\release\lib`). Add the include directory to your `INCLUDE` environment variable (`c:\gtk-build\gtk\Win32\release\include`), and run the `setup build` script for the Cairo first. If build finished OK, run `setup bdist_wininst`. It will generate an installation exe file in the `dist` subdirectory. Run this exe (as an administrator), and you should have PyCairo installed.

The build for the PyGobject is the same.

If the `setup build` complains that it cannot find some `.lib` or `.include` file, just find which folder are they in, somewhere in your `gtk-build\gtk\Win32\release\' folder. Include that folder in`LIB`or`INCLUDE` variable and run again.

HTH, Tom

Comment: Does it also installs GTK binaries? I just installed Anaconda and pygobject, and tried the test (https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but it breaks with: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.